# How to programmatically clear the Kerberos ticket cache

Tags: c#, c++, windows, kerberos

Does anyone know how to clear out the Kerberos ticket cache on the local computer - using managed \ unmanaegd code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need to do a call to [LsaCallAuthenticationPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378261(VS.85).aspx) using [KERB_PURGE_TKT_CACHE_REQUEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378104(VS.85).aspx) after using either [LsaConnectUntrusted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378265(VS.85).aspx) or [LsaRegisterLogonProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378318(VS.85).aspx).  Sorry no specifics, but I don't have my code for this around...

Comment: Hi,
It works excellent.
In addition, is there a managed way to do that?

Comment: Wrapping in pInvokes for managed code. See if these are at pInvoke.Net, if not, that site has got tons of information.

Comment: Yes, PInvoke works, but I wonder if there is a built in classes in the dot net framework to do that.

Comment: @rursw1 Please excuse the previous  unrelated comment. This is the only way to contact users in SO :).  I will remove it as I get Christopher_G_Lewis' response or by Aug 29.Please ping me if you want comment removed earlier than Aug 29.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way is to take the source code of Microsoft's KList (Included in the platform SDK\ Samples), and to do like them...

Answer (score 2):

There is a "managed C#" example of purging kerberos tickets using pInvoke at https://github.com/ErtiEelmaa/StackOverflow/blob/master/GroupPolicyUtilities.cs

Way too long to copy/paste here. It took some time since structures in pInvoke were invalid(eg someone though C++ LONG is equal to C# LONG and yada-yada), however, I've tested this one, and it worked for me.

Also, I noticed that the Windows server 2003 **klist.c** has few bugs in PurgeTicket:

- it does not clean up the response
- it double-checks the same "RESULT", instead of checking "RESULT" and then "SUB-RESULT"

Comment: Thank you - first for the reference (although it's PInvoke, so not exactly managed...) and second for MSFT's KList bugs. I'll check my code and fix the bugs if they are there.

Answer (score 0):

The simple, stupid way:

```
system("kdestroy");
```

Or if you want to be more legit, just check out the [source](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#B5Vhsv81OW0/~thn/ktelnet/beta/WinKrb-010403.zip|3AUOUBuE2Eo/appl/CMDLINE.W32/KDESTROY.C&q=kdestroy) of a `kdestroy` implementation.  `krb5_cc_destroy()` seems to be the relevant function call.