# Windows API to get information about cached Kerberos tickets

Tags: c#, powershell, winapi, kerberos, klist

I understand that I can get what I need by running "klist.exe" and parsing the output, but I'm wondering if there is a Windows/C#/Powershell API to get information about cached Kerberos tickets on Windows server.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft already provides a set of scripts for this. So, you don't have to write this from scratch. [Viewing and Purging Cached Kerberos Tickets](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tspring/2014/06/23/viewing-and-purging-cached-kerberos-tickets/) and yes they have klist in the mix. Otherwise, you end up trying to leverage …

```
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]
```

… and then doing SID translations and the like or you end up going down the same discussion in this Q&A.

[How to programmatically clear the Kerberos ticket cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266452/how-to-programmatically-clear-the-kerberos-ticket-cache)

Or leveraging these resources and tweaking as needed.

[Kerberos Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Keberos-Module-3a6ab12a)
The module gives access to the Kerberos ticket cache. It can read and purge tickets of the current logon session.

[A Managed Code validator for Kerberos tickets](https://github.com/SteveSyfuhs/Kerberos.NET)

> The Point of Kerberos.NET is to make Kerberos much easier to work with
>   in such scenarios. This is done by removing any hard dependencies on
>   Windows and moving all ticket processing to the application itself.
>   This of course means you don't need the application to be on a
>   domain-joined machine, and it probably doesn't need to be on Windows
>   either.
>
> ```
> Install-Package Kerberos.NET
> ```
>
> Using the Library
>
> Ticket authentication occurs in two stages. The first stage validates
>   the ticket for correctness via an IKerberosValidator with a default
>   implementation of KerberosValidator. The second stage involves
>   converting the ticket in to a usable ClaimsIdentity, which occurs in
>   the KerberosAuthenticator.
>
> The easiest way to get started is to create a new
>   KerberosAuthenticator and calling Authenticate. If you need to tweak
>   the behavior of the conversion, you can do so by overriding the
>   ConvertTicket(DecryptedData data) method.
>
> ```
> var authenticator = new KerberosAuthenticator(new KeyTable(File.ReadAllBytes("sample.keytab")));
>
> var identity = authenticator.Authenticate("YIIHCAYGKwYBBQUCoIIG...");
>
> Assert.IsNotNull(identity);
>
> var name = identity.Name;
>
> Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(name));
> ```
>
> Note that the constructor parameter for the authenticator is a
>   KeyTable. The KeyTable is a common format used to store keys on other
>   platforms. You can either use a file created by a tool like ktpass, or
>   you can just pass a KerberosKey during instantiation and it'll have
>   the same effect.

***List All Cached Kerberos Tickets***

When administering or troubleshooting authentication in a domain there are times when you need to know whether a ticket for a user and service are cached on a computer. This script exports all user's cached tickets on a computer to a text file for review.

***Download :*** [GetKerbTix.ps1](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/List-All-Cached-Kerberos-5ba41829)

***Purge All Kerberos Tickets***

There are situations where an administrator may want to clear the cached Kerberos tickets on a server. For example, user Bob left the company. In situations like that you can run this script to clear all cached Kerberos tickets and TGTs for all sessions on the computer.

***Download :*** [PurgeAllKerbTickets.ps1](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Purge-All-Kerberos-Tickets-13e5abfb)

```
#************************************************ 
# GetKerbTix.ps1 
# Version 1.0 
# Date: 6-11-2014 
# Author: Tim Springston [MSFT] 
# Description: On a specific computer the script is ran on,  
#  this script finds all logon sessions which have Kerberos 
#     tickets cached and enumerates the tickets and any ticket granting tickets. 
# The tickets may be from remote or interactive users and may be  
#  any logon type session (network, batch, interactive, remote interactive...). 
# This script will run on Windows Server 2008/Vista and later. 
#************************************************ 
cls 
$FormatEnumerationLimit = -1 
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME 
$UserName = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().name 
$ComputerDomain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetComputerDomain().name 
$Date = Get-Date 


#Prepare an output file to place info into. 
$ExportFile = "C:\windows\temp\" + $ComputerName + "_CachedKerberosTickets.txt" 
"Cached Kerberos Tickets" | Out-File $ExportFile -Encoding utf8 
"Logged on User:$UserName" | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 
"Computer name: $ComputerName" | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 
"Computer Domain: $ComputerDomain" | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 
"Date: $Date" | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 
"************************************" | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 

function GetKerbSessions 
    { 
    $Sessions = @() 
    $WMILogonSessions = gwmi win32_LogonSession 
    foreach ($WMILogonSession in $WMILogonSessions) 
        { 
        $LUID = [Convert]::ToString($WMILogonSession.LogonID, 16) 
        $LUID = '0x' + $LUID 
        $Sessions += $LUID 
        } 
    return $sessions 
    } 

function GetKerbSessionInfo 
    { 
    $OS = gwmi win32_operatingsystem 
    $sessions = New-Object PSObject 
    if ($OS.Buildnumber -ge 9200) 
        { 
        $KlistSessions = klist sessions 
        $Counter = 0 

        foreach ($item in $KlistSessions) 
            { 
            if ($item -match "^\[.*\]") 
                { 
                $LogonId = $item.split(' ')[3] 
                $LogonId = $LogonId.Replace('0:','') 
                $Identity = $item.split(' ')[4] 
                $Token5 = $item.Split(' ')[5] 
                $AuthnMethod = $Token5.Split(':')[0] 
                $LogonType = $Token5.Split(':')[1] 
                $Session = New-Object PSObject 
                Add-Member -InputObject $Session -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SessionID" -Value $LogonId 
                Add-Member -InputObject $Session -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Identity" -Value $Identity 
                Add-Member -InputObject $Session -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Authentication Method" -Value $AuthnMethod             
                Add-Member -InputObject $Session -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Logon Type" -Value $LogonType 

                Add-Member -InputObject $sessions -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $LogonId -Value $Session 
                $Session = $null 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    if ($OS.Buildnumber -lt 9200) 
        { 
        $WMILogonSessions = gwmi win32_LogonSession 
        foreach ($WMILogonSession in $WMILogonSessions) 
            { 
            $LUID = [Convert]::ToString($WMILogonSession.LogonID, 16) 
            $LUID = '0x' + $LUID 
            $Session = New-Object PSObject 
            Add-Member -InputObject $Session -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SessionID" -Value $LUID 
            Add-Member -InputObject $Session -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Identity" -Value "Not available" 
            Add-Member -InputObject $Session -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Authentication Method" -Value $WMILogonSession.AuthenticationPackage         
            Add-Member -InputObject $Session -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Logon Type" -Value $WMILogonSession.LogonType 

            Add-Member -InputObject $sessions -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $LUID -Value $Session 
            $Session = $null 
            } 
        } 
    return $sessions 
    } 

function ReturnSessionTGTs 
    { 
    param ($SessionID = $null) 
    if ($SessionID -eq $null) 
        { 
        $RawTGT =  klist.exe tgt 
        } 
        else 
            { 
            $RawTGT =  klist.exe tgt -li $sessionID 
            } 
    $TGT = @() 
    foreach ($Line in $RawTGT) 
        { 
        if ($Line.length -ge 1) 
            { 
            $TGT += $Line 
            } 
        } 
    if ($TGT -contains 'Error calling API LsaCallAuthenticationPackage (Ticket Granting Ticket substatus): 1312') 
        {$TGT = 'No ticket granting ticket cached in session.'} 
    return $TGT 
    }     

function ReturnSessionTickets  
    { 
    param ($SessionID = $null) 
    $OS = gwmi win32_operatingsystem 
    if ($SessionID -eq $null) 
        { 
        $TicketsArray =  klist.exe tickets 
        } 
        else 
            { 
            $TicketsArray =  klist.exe tickets -li $sessionID 
            } 
    $Counter = 0 
    $TicketsObject = New-Object PSObject 
    foreach ($line in $TicketsArray) 
        { 
        if ($line -match "^#\d") 
            { 
            $Ticket = New-Object PSObject 
            $Number = $Line.Split('>')[0] 
            $Line1 = $Line.Split('>')[1] 
            $TicketNumber = "Ticket " + $Number 
            $Client = $Line1 ;    $Client = $Client.Replace('Client:','') ; $Client = $Client.Substring(2) 
            $Server = $TicketsArray[$Counter+1]; $Server = $Server.Replace('Server:','') ;$Server = $Server.substring(2) 
            $KerbTicketEType = $TicketsArray[$Counter+2];$KerbTicketEType = $KerbTicketEType.Replace('KerbTicket Encryption Type:','');$KerbTicketEType = $KerbTicketEType.substring(2) 
            $TickFlags = $TicketsArray[$Counter+3];$TickFlags = $TickFlags.Replace('Ticket Flags','');$TickFlags = $TickFlags.substring(2) 
            $StartTime =  $TicketsArray[$Counter+4];$StartTime = $StartTime.Replace('Start Time:','');$StartTime = $StartTime.substring(2) 
            $EndTime = $TicketsArray[$Counter+5];$EndTime = $EndTime.Replace('End Time:','');$EndTime = $EndTime.substring(4) 
            $RenewTime = $TicketsArray[$Counter+6];$RenewTime = $RenewTime.Replace('Renew Time:','');$RenewTime = $RenewTime.substring(2) 
            $SessionKey = $TicketsArray[$Counter+7];$SessionKey = $SessionKey.Replace('Session Key Type:','');$SessionKey = $SessionKey.substring(2) 

            Add-Member -InputObject $Ticket -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Client" -Value $Client 
            Add-Member -InputObject $Ticket -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Server" -Value $Server 
            Add-Member -InputObject $Ticket -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "KerbTicket Encryption Type" -Value $KerbTicketEType 
            Add-Member -InputObject $Ticket -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Ticket Flags" -Value $TickFlags 
            Add-Member -InputObject $Ticket -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Start Time" -Value $StartTime 
            Add-Member -InputObject $Ticket -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "End Time" -Value $EndTime 
            Add-Member -InputObject $Ticket -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Renew Time" -Value $RenewTime 
            Add-Member -InputObject $Ticket -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Session Key Type" -Value $SessionKey 

            if ($OS.BuildNumber -ge 9200) 
                { 
                $CacheFlags =  $TicketsArray[$Counter+8];$CacheFlags = $CacheFlags.Replace('Cache Flags:','');$CacheFlags = $CacheFlags.substring(2) 
                $KDCCalled = $TicketsArray[$Counter+9];$KDCCalled = $KDCCalled.Replace('Kdc Called:','');$KDCCalled = $KDCCalled.substring(2) 
                Add-Member -InputObject $Ticket -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Cache Flags" -Value $CacheFlags 
                Add-Member -InputObject $Ticket -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "KDC Called" -Value $KDCCalled 
                } 
            Add-Member -InputObject $TicketsObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $TicketNumber -Value $Ticket 
            $Ticket = $null 
            } 
        $Counter++ 


        } 
    return $TicketsObject 
    }     

$OS = gwmi win32_operatingsystem 
$sessions = getkerbsessions 
$sessioninfo = GetKerbSessionInfo 
foreach ($Session in $sessions) 
{     
    #Get Session details as well 
    $currentsessioninfo = $sessioninfo.$session 
    $ID = $currentsessioninfo.identity 
    $SessionID = $currentsessioninfo.SessionID 
    $LogonType = $currentsessioninfo.'Logon Type' 
    $AuthMethod = $currentsessioninfo.'Authentication Method' 
    if ($OS.Buildnumber -lt 9200) 
        { 
        Write-Host "Kerberos Tickets for LogonID $SessionID" 
        "Kerberos Tickets for LogonID $SessionID" | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 
        } 
        else 
        { 
        Write-Host "Kerberos Tickets for $ID" 
        "Kerberos Tickets for $ID" | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 
        } 
    Write-Host "*****************************" 
     "*****************************" | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 
    Write-Host "Logon Type: $LogonType" 
    "Logon Type: $LogonType" | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 
    Write-host "Session ID: $SessionID" 
    "Session ID: $SessionID" | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 
    Write-host "Auth Method: $AuthMethod" 
    "Auth Method: $AuthMethod" | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 
    $SessionTickets = ReturnSessionTickets $Session 


    $TGT = ReturnSessionTGTs $SessionID 
    $TGT | FL * 
    $TGT | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 

    if ($SessionTickets -notmatch 'Ticket') 
        { 
        Write-Host "Session TGT: No tickets for this session in cache." 
        "Session TGT: No tickets for this session in cache." | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 
        } 
        else 
        { 
        $SessionTickets | FL * 
        $SessionTickets    | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 
        } 
    Write-Host "`n" 
     "`n" | Out-File $ExportFile -Append -Encoding utf8 

} 


#************************************************
# PurgeAllKerbTickets.ps1
# Version 1.0
# Date: 6-12-2014
# Author: Tim Springston [MSFT]
# Description: On a specific computer the script is ran on, 
#  this script finds all logon sessions which have Kerberos
#  tickets cached and for each session purges the ticket granting
#   tickets and the tickets using klist.exe.
#************************************************
cls

function GetKerbSessions
    {
    $Sessions = @()
    $WMILogonSessions = gwmi win32_LogonSession
    foreach ($WMILogonSession in $WMILogonSessions)
        {
        $LUID = [Convert]::ToString($WMILogonSession.LogonID, 16)
        $LUID = '0x' + $LUID
        $Sessions += $LUID
        }
    return $sessions
    }

Write-Host "WARNING: This script will purge all cached Kerberos tickets on the local computer for all sessions (whether interactive, network or other sessions)."  -backgroundcolor Red 
Write-Host "In a well-connected environment clients will request and obtain Kerberos tickets on demand without interruption. If not well-connected to a domain controller (remote network) then further network resource authentication may fail or use NTLM if tickets are purged." -BackgroundColor red
Write-Host "Confirm whether to purge by entering YES"
$Response = Read-Host

if ($Response -match 'YES')
    {
    $sessions = GetKerbSessions

    foreach ($Session in $sessions)
        {
        $PurgedTix = klist.exe -li $Session purge
        }
    Write-Host "All tickets purged!" -backgroundcolor green
    }
    else
        {
        Write-Host "Confirmation not received. NOT purging tickets." -backgroundcolor yellow
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I was able to find source code for klist.exe and "LsaCallAuthenticationPackage" seems to be the way to communicate with Kerberos cache in Windows:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/security/authorization/klist/KList.c

```
Status = LsaCallAuthenticationPackage(
            LogonHandle,
            PackageId,
            &CacheRequest,
            sizeof(CacheRequest),
            (PVOID *) &CacheResponse,
            &ResponseSize,
            &SubStatus
            );
if (!SEC_SUCCESS(Status) || !SEC_SUCCESS(SubStatus))
{
    ShowNTError("LsaCallAuthenticationPackage", Status);
    printf("Substatus: 0x%x\n",SubStatus);
    return FALSE;
}

printf("\nCached Tickets: (%lu)\n", CacheResponse->CountOfTickets);
for (Index = 0; Index < CacheResponse->CountOfTickets ; Index++ )
{
    printf("\n   Server: %wZ@%wZ\n",
        &CacheResponse->Tickets[Index].ServerName,
        &CacheResponse->Tickets[Index].RealmName);
```